# SwiftUI - Animate view transition and position change at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a yellow container with a green view inside. I want to move the container while also hiding/showing the inner green view, with an animation. Currently, I'm using [`.offset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(x:y:)) for the movement, and an `if` statement for the green view's transition.

The problem is, although the yellow container moves, the green view does not. It simply fades in and out at the destination offset. I want it to also move alongside the yellow container.

| This is what I get currently | This is what I want |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Yellow container moves right and left while the green inner view fades in and out. The green view stays on the right side] | [image: Yellow container moves right and left along with the green inner view, which also fades in and out.] |

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSubview = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Subview") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    showingSubview.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            if showingSubview {
                Text("Subview")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .offset(x: showingSubview ? 150 : 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

How can I make the green view move along with the yellow container, as it fades in and out? Preferably, I'd like to keep using `if` or `switch` statements for the insertion/removal.

Comment: @George unfortunately, that was just a prototype that I made in Figma

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution a year later, and it's really simple — just add `.scaleEffect(1)`!

```
.clipped() /// prevent the green view from overflowing
.scaleEffect(1) /// the magic modifier!
```

This is a much cleaner solution that doesn't involve setting custom frames or whatever. Also, it works with `if` and `switch` statements!

<kbd>[image: Yellow container moves right and left along with the green inner view, which also fades in and out.]</kbd>

I'm not completely sure why `.scaleEffect(1)` works, but it has something to do with how SwiftUI composes views. I think the modifier makes SwiftUI render it as a new group? If anyone knows why, I'd appreciate an answer.

Here's the full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSubview = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Subview") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    showingSubview.toggle()
                }
            }

            if showingSubview {
                Text("Subview")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .clipped() /// 1.
        .scaleEffect(1) /// 2.
        .offset(x: showingSubview ? 150 : 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the tip with `scaleEffect` - it also solved my animation issues with views being optionally rendered in a `VStack`. I wonder if `scaleEffect` modifies the default animation to render size changes differently? Curious.

Comment: There was a similar question asked in this year's WWDC Digital Lounge with an answer from an Apple engineer saying that you should use `.transformEffect(.identity)`. `.scaleEffect(1)` seems to do the exact same thing, but probably even less intuitive.

Comment: Thanks Mike. For the benefit of others who don't have access to the WWDC Digital Lounge, here is what the Apple engineer mentioned: "this occurs because animations occur at the level of the children within the container by default. When a new child appears mid-transition, it comes in at its destination position.
As a workaround, you can apply the `.transformEffect(.identity)` modifier to the container, which will cause layout animations to occur at the level of the container. This should give you the behavior that you are after."

Answer (score 7):

You can just change the height as it animates.

#### Code version #1

This will not fade and appears inside the yellow rectangle.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSubview = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button("Show Subview") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    showingSubview.toggle()
                }
            }

            Text("Subview")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .padding(.top)
                .frame(height: showingSubview ? nil : 0, alignment: .top)
                .clipped()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .offset(x: showingSubview ? 150 : 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

#### Result #1

[image: Result 1]

#### Code version #2

This version will fade out and appear at bottom edge, as your GIF shows.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSubview = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button("Show Subview") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    showingSubview.toggle()
                }
            }

            Text("Subview")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .padding(.top)
                .frame(height: showingSubview ? nil : 0, alignment: .top)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .clipped()
                .opacity(showingSubview ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .padding([.horizontal, .top])
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .padding(.bottom)
        .offset(x: showingSubview ? 150 : 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

#### Result #2

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Hmm, so render the subview in the beginning and just make it transparent? I would have liked to use `if`, but if this is the only way, it's good enough for me. Also what's the `fixedSize` for? I get the same result without it.

Comment: @aheze Yep, you're right that the fixedSize can be removed. I was using it when solving it and didn't realise it was no longer needed. And the `if` doesn't work because then you are only animating from when the view entered or left the hierarchy - which doesn't change its position. Remember that technically these properties change instantly, but SwiftUI just animates the visible changes. Settings the opacity to `0` should have negligible performance difference to removing it from the hierarchy (although I don't actually know which would be faster, since views with `0` opacity are optimised).

Comment: @aheze: But how could be George's answer solve your issue/question? I mean you have `if` in view, but the answer renders that Text all time from beginning.

Comment: @swiftPunk yeah, the answer wasn't exactly what I was looking for. But it seems like there's no other way currently.

Comment: Found a cleaner solution! https://stackoverflow.com/a/76094274/14351818

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 17 there is now a [`geometryGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/geometrygroup()) view modifier that solves this issue.

Note that this newer modifier can work where other transformation-based solutions, such as `.transformEffect(.identity)` or `.scaleEffect(1)`, will not, for example for transitions in widgets.

Here is the modified solution:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingSubview = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Subview") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    showingSubview.toggle()
                }
            }

            if showingSubview {
                Text("Subview")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .clipped() // Clip to disable overflow
        .geometryGroup() // Align descendant transitions with this view
        .offset(x: showingSubview ? 150 : 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```